# Sorting data Firebase database latest to oldest

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am using the following to retrieve the data on HTML page but what I want is that latest entries should come on top of table which I am not able to get. Kindly resolve this issue.

```
  databaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
   var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
   var childData = childSnapshot.val();
   
   var row = tblUsers.insertRow(rowIndex);
   var cellId = row.insertCell(0);
   var cellName = row.insertCell(1);
   var cellEmail = row.insertCell(2);
   var cellMsg = row.insertCell(3);
   cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.name));
   cellEmail.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.email));
   cellMsg.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.message));
   
   rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have stored firebase objects under keys generated with `ref.push()` method, then you need to know that push keys are timestamp based values. Therefore you can try to get your data like this:

```js
databaseRef.orderByKey().once('value', /* ... */ );
```

Then objects will be ordered by its keys in ascending order(older first, newer later). Then, if you store the retrieved data objects in an array just perform a `objectArray.reverse()` to get it in a descending way.

I'm not sure if this is a suitable approach to deal with your problem since it involves client side processing when array is ordered.

I'm sure you have dig on this [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order), however I think that is all you can get without additional work.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! will get back on this.